# Is there any way to report only declared licences using Maven?

Tags: maven, dependency-management, license-maven-plugin

I know that there is an ability to check third-party licenses in your project using 
[License Maven plug-in](https://www.mojohaus.org/license-maven-plugin/index.html). 
Specifically using **mvn license:third-party-report** goal.
However, the problem is that the report will include both *declared* and *transitive* dependencies.

I wonder is there any way to report only *declared* dependency licenses(meaning only those that are present in *pom.xml*)?